# Swiping panels within Android activity

Tags: android, panel, swipe

I am trying to emulate the Recipes section of the Epicurious Android application, where each recipe is shown in one panel, and swiping left/right will lead to the next recipe being shown.

Any one has any idea how to implement this type of layout, as the [Hello Views tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) does not seem to have anything similar to this.

[image: Epicurious screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this: [Horizontal Swiping with View Pager](http://goo.gl/Rt79X)

Comment: I think viewflipper kinda fits my requirements better. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)?

Comment: I read it up briefly. Seems to be what im looking for. Thanks!